# 配列の中に複数の条件全てみたすレコードを抽出する

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

対象はGooleCloudBigqueryですが、Postgres等Arrayを持っているDBも同様と思います

id:1, arr_val: [{"a":"111"},{"a":"222"},{"a":"333"}]
id:2, arr_val: [{"a":"222"},{"a":"444"},{"a":"666"}]
・・・

といったデータ構造の時に
"a"が111と222両方を含む要素を持ったレコードを抽出したいです。
(例の場合id1のレコードが引っかかるようにしたいです。)

```
  SELECT
    arr_val
  FROM
    `テーブル名`,
    UNNEST(arr_val) AS line
  WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(line.a, r"正規表現") )  #条件1
    and
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(line.a, r"正規表現") )  #条件2
```

の様にやってみましたが、条件が一つの時はそれぞれうまく行きますが
AND条件とすると検索結果が0となってしまいました。

Comment: 動作する最小限のコードとしてテーブル設計などを記載していただいた方が良いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO本家の方で回答頂きましたので転記いたします。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481011/how-to-extract-record-using-multiple-filter-to-array

---

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

## standardSQL

```
SELECT id, arr_val
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM t.arr_val line WHERE a IN (111, 222))
```